# Group homology with coefficients vanish

Tags: representation-theory, algebraic-number-theory, homological-algebra

Say $G$ is a group and $M$ is a $\mathbb ZG$-module with the property that $H_i(G;M)=0$ for all $i\ge 0$. Does this happen besides $M=0$?

Comment: If you only require trivial homology for $i > 0$, then this will be true for any flat module and hence also true for free modules. $H_{0}(G, M)$ is the coinvariant module of $M$ and off the top of my head I do not know when this will be 0.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Let $G$ be cyclic of order $2$, and let $M=\mathbb{Q}$ with the generator of $G$ acting by multiplication by $-1$.

Or more generally, $G$ could be any finite group and $M$ any $\mathbb{Q}G$-module that does not contain a trivial submodule.

Comment: One should add that $H_*(E_*G\otimes_{\mathbb ZG} \operatorname{Res}_{\mathbb Z G}^{\mathbb Q} M) \cong H_*( \tilde E_*G\otimes_{\mathbb QG} M)$ for any $\mathbb QG$-module $M$ a free $\mathbb ZG$-resolution $E_*G$ of $\mathbb Z$ and $\tilde E_*G = E_*G \otimes_{\mathbb Z} \mathbb Q = E_*G\otimes_{\mathbb ZG} \mathbb QG$. This is for the fact that $\mathbb Q$ is a flat $\mathbb Z$-module.